# Highcharts reloading issue with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, charts, highcharts

I'm struggling to solve a problem I have with getting a chart to be redrawn after navigating to another view and then return back to the same chart view.

I'm using Backbone.js and Underscore as a MVC and templating solution for my application.
When I navigate to the charting page initially it works great, but if I move away and then come back I get a `TypeError: chart.series[0] is undefined in the console log.

I have highlighted line where the error occurs in the code below, close to the end.

My thought is that I may need to destroy() the chart at some point, but I'm unsure where I would do this and if it would solve my problem.

I recently changed the script to now use HighStock 'Highstock JS v1.3.6 (2013-10-04)' from earlier HighCharts ver 2.3.5, where it appeared that I did not have this issue.

The app is live online if anyone really needs or wants to see it in action, let me know.

The following code section is the function thatis called by the Backbone router.
If there is a need for other sections of code, please let me know.

I'll be grateful for any advice.

**EDIT:**
I have managed to get this in JSFiddle for anyone to view the problem.
Clickty clack your fury tailless one here [http://jsfiddle.net/rockwallaby/pqKWj](http://jsfiddle.net/rockwallaby/pqKWj/5/)

When you first run it up, you will get a trend being displayed.
Then hit the 'Go to a different page' link, you will get a fairly blank page.
On that page there is a link to bring you back to the trend page.
Hitting that link brings you back but the trend does not get rendered correctly due to the above mentioned error.

```
//=================================================================================
//  trendsBattery
//  A simple trend view showing Battery Volts and Solar Charge
//
window.trendsBattery = Backbone.View.extend({
trendModel: new TrendsModel(),
template: _.template(trendsTemplate),
chart: null,

chartoptions:{
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart-container',
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    title:{
        text:'Battery Volts & Solar Amps'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type:'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {month:'%e. %b',year:'%b'}
    },
    yAxis: [{
            title :{text: 'Battery Volts'},
            min: 22,
            max: 32,
            minorGridLineColor: '#E0E0E0',
    },
    {
            title :{text: 'Solar Charge Amps'},
            min: 0,
            max: 16,
            opposite: true,
    },
    ],
    series:[
        {yAxis: 0, data: [], type: 'line', step: true, name: 'Battery Vdc'},
        {yAxis: 1, data: [], type: 'line', step: true, name: 'Solar Amps'},
    ],
},

render:function() {
    that = this;
    $(this.el).html(this.template());
    this.chartoptions.chart.width = (windowWidth);
    this.chartoptions.chart.height = (windowHeight - 150);
    setTimeout(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(that.chartoptions);
        chart.events ={load: that.requestData(this.chart) };
    },20);
    return this;
},
requestData: function(chart){

    var querystring = '//myHostServer.com/myFolder/myPHP.php';
    jQuery.get(querystring, null, function(csv, state, xhr) {
        if (typeof csv !== 'string') {
            csv = xhr.responseText;
        };
        csv = csv.split(/\n/g);
        var vB_array = [];
        var iS_array = [];

        jQuery.each(csv, function (i, line) {
            if (line.length > 1) {
                line_array = line.split(',');
                var date = parseInt(line_array[0]) * 1000;
                var vBpoint = {};
                var iSpoint = {};
                vBpoint.x = date;
                iSpoint.x = date;
                vBpoint.y = parseFloat(line_array[1]);
                iSpoint.y = parseFloat(line_array[4]);
                vB_array.unshift(vBpoint);
                iS_array.unshift(iSpoint);
            };
        });
            chart.series[0].setData(vB_array, false);  // <<<<< Problem Area
            chart.series[1].setData(iS_array, false);
            chart.redraw();
    });
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes();    // expand out the scrollbar when moving through time:
    },
});
```

Comment: Edited and reduced code for better readability. Just to confirm, this code works on first call only, and generates the mentioned error on subsequent calls.

Comment: Not very sure about exact issue here, but what I smell somethings wrong with the code chartoptions is a prototype property of the trendsBattery class, if it happens to get changed over the lifecycle of the view, that will update the prototype, hence next time when you try rendering the chart you will not have original chartoptions but modified chartoptions.  Instead if you can replace it with a function to return a fresh object every time it get called this might fix your problem. try it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just updated jsfiddle with the suggestion I provided in comment, it's working.

```
window.trendView = Backbone.View.extend({
    trendModel: new TrendsModel(),
    template: _.template(trendTemplate),
    chart: null,
    getChartOptions: function () {
        return {
            chart: {
                animation: true,
                renderTo: 'chart-container',
                backgroundColor: '#fff'
            },
            rangeSelector: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Battery Volts & Solar Amps'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    month: '%e. %b',
                    year: '%b'
                } // don't display the dummy year:
            },
            yAxis: [{
                title: {
                    text: 'Battery Volts'
                },
                min: 22,
                max: 32,
                minorGridLineColor: '#E0E0E0'
            }, {
                title: {
                    text: 'Solar Charge Amps'
                },
                min: 0,
                max: 16,
                opposite: true
            }],
            series: [{
                yAxis: 0,
                data: [],
                type: 'line',
                step: true,
                name: 'Battery Vdc'
            }, {
                yAxis: 1,
                data: [],
                type: 'line',
                step: true,
                name: 'Solar Amps'
            }]
        }
    },

    render: function () {
        that = this;
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        var chartOptions = that.getChartOptions();
        chartOptions.chart.width = (windowWidth - 50);
        chartOptions.chart.height = (windowHeight - 50);
        setTimeout(function () {
            chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(chartOptions);
            chart.events = {
                load: that.requestData(this.chart)
            };
        }, 20);
        return this;
    },
    requestData: function (chart) {
        var querystring = '//paulalting.com/hydrosolar/clientGET.php?id=trendVolts&start=6400&size=200';
        console.log(querystring);
        jQuery.get(querystring, null, function (csv, state, xhr) {
            if (typeof csv !== 'string') {
                csv = xhr.responseText;
            }
            csv = csv.split(/\n/g);
            var vB_array = [];
            var iS_array = [];

            jQuery.each(csv, function (i, line) {
                if (line.length > 1) {
                    line_array = line.split(',');
                    var date = parseInt(line_array[0], 10) * 1000;
                    var vBpoint = {};
                    var iSpoint = {};
                    vBpoint.x = date;
                    iSpoint.x = date;
                    vBpoint.y = parseFloat(line_array[1]);
                    iSpoint.y = parseFloat(line_array[4]);
                    vB_array.unshift(vBpoint);
                    iS_array.unshift(iSpoint);
                }
            });
            chart.series[0].setData(vB_array, false); // <<<<< Problem Area
            chart.series[1].setData(iS_array, false);
            chart.redraw();
        });
        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(); // expand out the scrollbar when moving through time:
    }
});
```

here is the link

http://jsfiddle.net/pqKWj/14/

If you are interested let me know I see some more similar problems in the code, which I think fine for now, but will create issues, when you have 2 charts in the same page etc. we can talk

Comment: Ravi, this solution works. I have implemented it and it seems to do the trick. I changed chartOptions = that.blah to chartOptions = this.blah which improved the situation as I have a few charts, but not on the same page, but they do use the same DOM element at different times. Much appreciated, thankyou. If you have other suggestions, let me know.

Comment: @rockwallaby the two concerns I had was  

`trendModel: new TrendsModel(),`
and
`chart:null`
these two doesn't qualify to be part of prototype, because for every instance of this view, you might want them to be different. Just do what you did for chartOptions on them

Comment: I have placed that in the initialised function, like     `    initialize: function() {
    this.trendModel = new TrendsModel();
    this.chart = null;}` All seems to be working now, many thanks Ravi